# Actual element tags are not getting captured

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt

I am using the below piece of XSL code to construct a span tag calling a javascript function on mouseover. The input to the javascipt should be a html table. The output from the variable "showContent" gives just the text content but not along with the table tags.
How can this be resolved.

XSL:

```
          <xsl:variable name="aTable" as="element()*">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <xsl:for-each select="$capturedTags">
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="node()" /></td></tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="start" select='concat("Tip(&#39;", "")'></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="end" select='concat("&#39;)", "")'></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="showContent">
                <xsl:value-of select='concat($start,$aTable,$end)'/> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" onmouseout="{$hideContent}" 
              onmouseover="{$showContent}" id="{$textNodeId}"><xsl:value-of select="$textNode"></xsl:value-of></span>
```

Actual Output:
`<span onmouseout="UnTip()" onmouseover="Tip('content1')" id="d1t14"`>is my `</span`>

Expected output:

```
   <span onmouseout="UnTip()" onmouseover="Tip('<table><tr><td>content1</td></tr>')" id="d1t14">is my </span>
```

What is the change that needs to done in the above XSL for the table, tr and td tags to get passed?

Answer (score 2):

The `concat()` function takes the string values of its arguments and concatenates them.

`$aTable` as defined has no string value.

**You may want to define it not as `element()*` but as `xs:string`.**

Then you'd need to escape the text in it, or to include it in a `CDATA` tag. Because the value of `$aTable` is dynamically generated, using `CDATA` isn't possible.

You'll need your own XML serialization processing to turn all tags markup into text. Even in this case, the contents of the `onmouseover` attribute will contain escaped characters, due to attribute value normalization.

Seems quite impossible.